# How to find total likes, comments, shares get in everyday in facebook in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am tried to get total number of likes, shares, comments get in everyday in facebook, but its not working. I am used Koala gem.

I tried this:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(ACCESS_TOKEN)
likes = graph.get_object(post_id, fields: 'likes.summary(true)', since: '2017-01-23', until: '2017-01-24')
shares = graph.get_object(post_id, fields: 'shares.summary(true)', since: '2017-01-23', until: '2017-01-24')
comments = graph.get_object(post_id, fields: 'comments.summary(true)', since: '2017-01-23', until: '2017-01-24')
```

Thanks in advance :)